# Java HTML Parsing a Page with Infinite Scroll

Tags: java, html, jsoup, infinite-scroll

How can I grab a page's HTML in java if the page has infinite scroll? I'm currently grabbing a page this way:

```
URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String html = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

But it doesn't return any of the content associated with the infinite scroll section of the page. How can I trigger this scrolling on the HTML page so that my Jsoup document contains this section?

Comment: Can you give the URL of website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinite scroll describes a technique where the page does not contain the content.  Some JavaScript code runs in the browser, sends a request to the server for addiional content and adds it to the page.  When you scroll towards the end of the available content, the JavaScript code repeats the process: it sends another request and adds the additional content.

Therefore, you need a web browser with a JavaScript engine that can run the JavaScript code and produce the events that cause the code to load content.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger this javascript from within a java application?

Comment: You could look into Selenium Webdriver.  There is a Java API to programmatically control a browser.  Otherwise you will need to actually implement an entire runtime that will interpret/execute the Javascript code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@dsh is right, the content is most likely loaded dynmically via AJAX. As an alternative to using a real browser, i.e. selenium webdriver, you may look into the network traffic and idetify the API call that the page triggers. You can maybe call that Api directly with Jsoup. Often the content is however not HTML but JSON, XML or some other format. It still may be very worth while doing this, since using webdriver is often pretty slow and resource-heavy.